# Command line - Some questions

Tags: command-line, batch-file, zip, archiving

I've created a batch file for zipping selected items in a folder.
(The file is placed in 'Send to').

If I use the following code:

`for %%* in (.) do set CurrentFolder=%%~n*
"C:\Program Files\WinRar\WinRar" a -afzip "%CurrentFolder%.xpi"`

- The file name is that of the current folder (correct).
- All files are archived whether I select one file or multiple files
  (wrong).
- Selected folders are not archived (wrong).

If I use the following code:

`set file=%~f1
"C:\Program Files\WinRar\WinRar" a -afzip "%file:~0,-4%.xpi" %1`

- The file name is that of the file on which I right click (correct).
- Only that file is archived even if multiple files are selected
  (wrong).

How can I know if a single item is selected or more?

What's the condition syntax?

How can I include folders in the archive?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you some...

```
@echo off
::Save passed parameter to a variable...
set _loc=%~1

::Check if passed parameter is a file/folder and process accordingly...
if exist "%~s1\*" (echo Processing all files in folder %_loc% && echo. && goto :ProcFolders) else (echo Processing files && echo. && goto :ProcFile)
goto :exit

::When passed parameter is a folder...
:ProcFolders
::Check if folder is empty...
dir /b /a:-d "%_loc%" >nul 2>&1 && (echo  Non-empty folder!) || (echo Checking for sub-folders... && goto :CheckSubDir)

:CheckSubDir
dir /b /a:-d /s "%_loc%\*">nul 2>&1 && (echo. && echo Subfolders/files exist) || (echo. && echo No file or subfolders found && goto :exit)

::If folder has files or subfolders with files, continue here.
for /f %%g in ('dir /b /a:-d /s "%_loc%\*.*"') do echo Processing %%g &&    echo.
goto :exit

::When passed parameter is a file...
:ProcFile
if "%~1"=="" goto :exit
echo Processing %~1 && echo.
shift
goto :ProcFile
goto :exit

:exit
pause
exit /b
```

The script checks if the passed parameter is a folder or individual files. If files, it will `shift` through the passed parameters and process each file individually. Be aware that you may hit a limitation in the number of characters that can be passed as an argument from the command prompt or drag and drop, so if a lot of files need to be processed, just process the entire folder. I've been able to pass 50+ files without a problem, but their names were relatively short. I've modified the script further to check for sub-directories as well.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help.

I was notified about your reply about an hour ago, and I've been trying to integrate the zip command into your script.

Comment: I'm not a developer, and it's complicated for me.
If I add "C:\Program Files\WinRar\WinRar" a -afzip "%_loc.xpi" to :ProcFile, each file is archived separately and this isn't what I want.

Also, if I select all items and right-click on a file, folders are not archived.

I'd be grateful for further assistance.


***
Pressing Enter in the Comment section, submits the content and I have to start a new one (you can only edit 5 times).

Comment: @Yaron I will modify the script later on tonight.

Comment: Thanks again. It's really kind of you.

I've googled a bit and found that when adding the switch "-r", WinRar includes folders in the archive.

So, apparently the following structure should work:
If (one item is selected)
set file=%~f1
"C:\Program Files\WinRar\WinRar" a -afzip "%file:~0,-4%.xpi" %1
Else
for %%* in (.) do set CurrentFolder=%%~n*
"C:\Program Files\WinRar\WinRar" a -afzip -r "%CurrentFolder%.xpi"
***
Two problems:
1) How can I know how many items are selected?
2) If only a folder is selected, the code should be changed.

Comment: I'll use the name of the first item, or folder, as the archive name. Shouldn't be that difficult to implement. Famous last words. ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... Thanks.
I'd like to emulate the behavior of the built-in "Compress to FileName.zip"